# Methods for solving nth order semilinear elliptic PDEs

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, fourier-transform

I am looking for names of methods, and examples of their use that can be used to find solutions for semilinear elliptic PDE equations of the below types:

$$\frac{\partial^ny}{\partial x^n}+\frac{\partial^ny}{\partial t^n}+\frac{\partial^{n-1}y}{\partial x^{n-1}}+\frac{\partial^{n-1}y}{\partial t^{n-1}}+...+\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial t^2}+\alpha\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}+\beta y(x,t)+\gamma=g(x,t)$$

Alternative notation:

$$\nabla^ny+\nabla^{n-1}y+...+\nabla^2y+\alpha y_t y_x+\beta y(x,t)+\gamma=g(x,t)$$

where $y=y(x,t)$, $y(x)$ and $y(t)$ can be solutions. $g(x,t)$ is assumed to be continuous and differentiable, and $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma \in \Re$ and <>0

Can one use eg Laplace Transforms to solve it? If no why not? If yes how?

Comment: Following the pattern, should it be 

$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} \color{red} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$$

or is it correct in it's current format? (Note: I realise that the PDE will be _linear_ if it is of the form I've stated, but it just seems like the pattern implies there should be a $+$ between the two derivatives, so I wanted to check).

Comment: Qs is correct in current format - PDE is non-linear

Comment: This is a so-called semilinear PDE. Look up techniques under that subheading. (There will be a great deal of literature for the case $n=2$.)

Comment: To be more specific, this is semilinear and "elliptic" type (i.e. if the semilinear term were removed, the resulting linear PDE would be elliptic).

Comment: I have searched google for "second order semilinear elliptic PDE", and found many research papers and books. However I have yet to come across examples with mixed partial term.

Comment: They won't be written in *literally* that form. Most of this work is about existence/uniqueness and linearization approximation, and for this purpose all that matters is that it is second order semilinear elliptic.

Comment: Ok so some of the methods they describe for other semilinear elliptic equations may/should work for equation in question?

Comment: At least in terms of existence/uniqueness machinery, absolutely.

Comment: Qs updated. Can one use Laplace transforms to solve it?

Comment: That depends on the domain and boundary conditions that are involved, but yes, that would help some. If you, say, take the Fourier transform in $x$, then you arrive at something that looks almost like a nonlinear ODE; it would be a nonlinear ODE if $g$ didn't depend on $x$. But this requires the right type of boundary conditions that this will actually make sense.

Comment: What are some names for methods that may work towards getting solutions?